# SQL Server Query Spatial Data for Nearest Neighbor DISTINCT TOP N ORDER BY Distance

Tags: sql-server, spatial, nearest-neighbor

I would like to know if there is a way to query nearest N neighbours from a spatial data column, discarding duplicates.

For example, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (@N) Point.STDistance(@Point) AS Distance
FROM MyTable
WHERE Point.STDistance(@Point) IS NOT NULL --For Spatial Index usage
ORDER BY Distance;
```

It is pretty much effective, but my results are:

```
Distance
3906,81969203873
3906,81969203873
5321,62614141754
5756,28719382942
```

I have tried to put a DISTINCT clause but then it doesn't use the spatial index.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When you say discarding duplicates, do you mean duplicate points or duplicate distances?  It is totally feasible for two points to be the same distance from another.  If you are looking for a list of unique points, just run your `top N` on a filtered version of `MyTable`.

Comment: Let's say duplicate distances. I can not have a filtered version of `MyTable` cause it has millions of rows

Comment: Why can you not filter it?  Do you not hold the latitude and longitude values in addition to your spatial points?  Or any other identifying information about where the point is besides the spatial point itself?

Comment: Insert this result into a temporary table, then select `distinct` rows from the temporary table.

Comment: If I insert it to a temporary table and then I filter, the number of rows I will get will be under `@N`

Comment: Let's consider the duplication criterion being distance for a moment. If that was the case, a `select distinct top(3) Distance` and the nearest items are 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, and 5 meters away. Do you really want your query to return 1, 2, and 5? I don't know your use case, but it seems odd.

Comment: That's exactly what I want my query to return

Answer (score 1):

As per MSDN description on [Nearest Neighbor Query and Spatial Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff929109.aspx), you need to use `STDistance()` in `ORDER BY` clause.

> 5. The first expression in the ORDER BY clause must use the STDistance() method.
> 6. Sort order for the first STDistance() expression in the ORDER BY clause must be ASC.

You might need to use `GROUP BY` or a `CTE` or a `subquery` to avoid any potential duplicates.

Comment: I don't need to specify `STDistance()` in the `ORDER BY`, because I am ordering by `Distance` wich is an alias of `Point.STDistance(@Point)`

Comment: If I use a `GROUP BY`, or a `CTE`, or a subquery, no spatial index is used then

Comment: @JesúsMuelaIzquierdo, Can you post the test table script, with test data insert scripts to simulate your problem and to help you? Please also tell us which version of SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score -2):

There are recursive records because of your table design or database design. if you share database or tables schema can answer more precise. Using inner select clean recursive records then apply the distance functions to get distance. It will use spatial index.

Comment: How is this recursive? It appears to be a simple spatial query to me.

Comment: 3906,81969203873
3906,81969203873 these two look so similer to me, this means repeatitive work on the same record. Do not think like classic programming logic on database. Terms expresses different things. good luck

Comment: Similar != recursive. Also, given the statement of problem from the original poster, it's likely that he has little control over the data in the table (i.e. it's going to be something like "locations of coffee shops" for rows). How would you suggest that he get rid of "similar" data and not lose track of the fact that, using my contrived example, that there are two coffee shops right next to each other?

Comment: Why do you think so complex.:) I just say, use inner select get just the intented records and then apply the geography function. What is wrong ? If the all problem is recursive !=similer yes it is true, but similer records leads to recursive works man :) (actually in middle tier in sql server not oracle)